# Instantiate class based on json value

Tags: c#, casting, activator

Say I have two classes :

```
public class male 
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int age { get; set; }
}

public class female 
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int age { get; set; }
}
```

I have some JSON data like so :

```
{
    "people" : [
        {
            "name" : "fred",
            "age" : 45,
            "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
            "name" : "jane",
            "age" : 45,
            "gender" : "female"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I wish to loop through this JSON data and depending on the gender of the person, instantiate the corresponding class.

For example :

```
JObject data = jsonData.people;

for(var i = 0; i< data.Count; i++) {
   JObject thisPerson = data[i];
   var instantiatePerson = new {thisPerson.gender}; //obviously this will not work
}
```

Now the above is just an example, hopefully that will explain what I need.

I have tried using the `Activator.CreateInstance` like so :

```
var type = Type.GetType("myNamespace" + person.gender);
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This verifies but I can't loop through the object and give the instantiated class the property values like so :

```
foreach(var key in person) {
   myObject[key] = person[key];
}
```

I get the error :

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object.

Which leads me to think I have to cast myObject to it's appropriate type, but how?

Comment: Both of those classes are exactly the same so why are they two different classes?

Comment: @maccettura it's just an example, my classes are different in my actual project

Comment: @maccettura That is irrelevant to the question. There may be other properties that are not being shown for simplification.

Comment: @JuanFerrer I don't think its irrelevant at all, this could very well be a class design problem.  The alternative is using reflection which isn't the greatest idea most of the time.

Comment: @thatOneGuy I think your issue might have a simpler solution.  It would help to see more of your class code if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, an object isn't an associative array of its properties. That's JavaScript. If you really need to do things this way, use reflection to set the properties.

Something like this:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = myObject.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var propInfo in props)
{
    if (person.ContainsKey(propInfo.Name))
    {
        propInfo.SetValue(myObject, person[propInfo.Name]);
    }
}
```

or

```
var type = myObject.GetType();

foreach (var key in person) {
    var prop = type.GetProperty(key);
    if (prop != null)
    {
         prop.SetValue(myObject, person[key]);
    }
}
```

But I think a better answer is that you should probably be redesigning your classes instead. `male` and `female` could be one `Person` class with a `gender` property as well as `name` and `age` -- exactly like what's in the JSON.

Conventional JSON serialization isn't broken. Is there really a compelling need to reinvent it?

Comment: As you can tell I am more familiar with Javascript like you had mentioned. I get the idea of your example, what type does 'person' have to be to have the 'ContainsKey' available ?

Comment: I think `person` would be a `Dictionary`, correct me if I am wrong Ed

Comment: Yes, my guess was that `person` is a `dynamic` something-or-other that supports `IDictionary`.

Comment: @thatOneGuy In case it doesn't have that, I just updated with a version that doesn't use it.